# como recuperar archivos modificados en git después de un git reset --hard

Tags: git

Hola comunidad mi pregunta es mu simple:
¿Como puedo recuperar archivos modificados después de hacer un git reset --hard? estos archivos no estaban involucrados en algún commit.

El commit que los involucra tiene 10 lineas de código menos, por lo tanto cuando hice el reset se borraron estas 10 linea, como las recupero.

Gracias

Comment: Si los cambios nunca han pasado por el repositorio (nunca hiciste `git add` con ellos), entonces `git` no puede hacer nada por recuperarlos. Dependes de otras utilidades de tu operativo (backups, sistemas de archivos con _journaling_, uso de copias automáticas en la nube como Dropbox, etc.) Si habían estado en algún commit, con `git reflog` aún puedes recuperar los hashes de esos commit y volver a ellos con `git checkout <hash>`

Comment: gracias @abulafia por tu respuesta, me toco buscar en la nube de respaldo.